# Array adding and set methods

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I am passing in an array to my class, I am constructing it and then I have the ability to transactions (replaces the array with new data) or add transactions (so if the array is first off size 10 then another 10 are added on to make it have 20 elements, the amount in the array may not always be 20 etc)

the code produces the correct results I am expecting when using the first two methods but not the add transaction method. which does not add another 10 elements as expected

does anyone know what issues they are in my coding?

I am fairly bound by the assignment structure in this one so working with the avaliable structures are ideal.

```
Transaction* tArray;
int nTransactions;

Analyser::Analyser(Transaction* transactions, int numTransactions)
{
    //contructs the array and the amount of transations
    tArray = transactions;
    nTransactions = numTransactions;
}

void Analyser::setTransactions(Transaction* transactions, int numTransactions)
{
    //set tArray to new set of transactions
    tArray = transactions;
}

void Analyser::addTransactions(Transaction* transactions, int numTransactions)
{

    Transaction* newT;
    newT = new Transaction[numTransactions + nTransactions];    

    for(int i = 0; i<nTransactions; i++)
    {
        newT[i] = tArray[i];
    }
    for (int j = nTransactions; j<numTransactions + nTransactions; j++ )
    {
        newT[j] = transactions[j-nTransactions];    
    }
    tArray = newT;
 }
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Does the program crash?

Comment: In `setTransactions`, you're not modifying `nTransactions`. This will cause errors if `tArray` and `transactions` are not of the same size.

Comment: what does a debugger say

Comment: no it runs correctly but gives the same results - as if it ignores the addtransaction method.

Comment: BTW - use std::vector

Comment: fyi you never clean up `tArray` before reassigning it to `newT`, this will be a memory leak.

Comment: @pm100 The OP says the following: "I am fairly bound by the assignment structure in this one so working with the avaliable structures are ideal."

Comment: do it with std::vector too for extra credit :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `addTransactions` code should look like this:

```
void Analyser::addTransactions(Transaction* transactions, int numTransactions)
{

    Transaction* newT;
    newT = new Transaction[numTransactions + nTransactions];    

    for(int i = 0; i<nTransactions; i++)
    {
        newT[i] = tArray[i];
    }
    for (int j = nTransactions; j<numTransactions + nTransactions; j++ )
    {
        newT[j] = transactions[j-nTransactions];    
    }
    delete[] tArray;
    tArray = newT;
    nTransactions += numTransactions;
 }
```

`delete[] tArray` makes sure that you're not leaking any memory. In this case, I am assuming that Analyser always owns tArray, even when the given pointer is just used as in the constructor and `setTransactions`.

`nTransactions += numTransactions;` makes sure that the size of the `tArray` is appropriately updated. You should also edit `setTransactions`, as mentioned before.

Comment: I believe this works! - thanks a lot for your help and all the commenters :)

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
void Analyser::setTransactions(Transaction* transactions, int numTransactions)
{
//set tArray to new set of transactions
tArray = transactions;
ntransactions = numTransactions //HERE YOU NEED TO UPDATE THIS TOO
 }
```

As stated in the comments, also in here:

```
 void Analyser::addTransactions(Transaction* transactions, int numTransactions)
 {

    nTransactions += numTransactions; 

    Transaction* newT;
    newT = new Transaction[nTransactions];    //Enough for all transactions

    for(int i = 0; i< nTransactions; i++)
    {
        newT[i] = tArray[i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j< numTransactions; j++ )
    {
         newT[nTransactions - numTransactions + j] = transactions[j];    
    }
    tArray = newT;

 }
```

Comment: I added the line which you mention however it stills seem like the addtransaction code is not working - if I comment it out or not the results remain the same.

Comment: You also forgot to update `nTransactions` in `addTransactions`. Use `nTransactions += numTransactions`.

Comment: I am now getting a memory error when i add that line in the add transaction code. Access violation reading location 0xabababab.

Comment: on the final iteration in the first loop - the answer is right in front of me but I brain is not working lol

Comment: @user2075995 Make sure the line is added at the end of the function, as in my answer. If you add it at the beginning of your function, `tArray` (the old one) will be assumed to be larger than it really is, and you will be reading values past the end of the array that aren't really there.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the line

```
nTransactions = numTransactions;
```

in your setTransactions. Your constructor should simply call your setTransactions method, so you have that code only once.

Comment: I added the line which you mention however it stills seem like the addtransaction code is not working - if I comment it out or not the results remain the same